# Need help to stop my Java Swing GUI timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I want to start and stop my timer by clicking buttons. But the stop button doesn't work. How should I fix this?

I'm working on a project which contains a Timer along with other features. All I want to do is Start and Stop my timer by using Buttons.

import javax.swing.Timer;

```
JButton startbut=new JButton("Start");
JButton endbut=new JButton("Mark As Done");
private void addActionEvent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startbut.addActionListener(this);
}
int s=0,h=0;
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    if(e.getSource()==startbut) {
        t=new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                time.setText(String.valueOf(h+"m:"+s+"s"));
                s++;
                
                if(s==60) {
                
                    h++;
                    s=0;
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        });
        
        
        t.start();
        
        
        
    }
    if(e.getSource()==endbut) {
        t.stop();
    }
    
    
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't see an action listener added to `endbut`?

Comment: You didn't register an `ActionListener` for `endbut`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that endbut dosen't has action listener, so when the button is get clicked nothing is happen t.stop(); never get call. we need to register endbut to the same action listenerd so that when it get clicked actionPerformed is get called (t.stop)

```
endbut.addActionListener(this);
```

after

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startbut.addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: Adding some commentary will go a long way to explain why this solves the OP's question. Just a code dump alone is not that helpful.

Comment: okay, the the problem is that endbut dosen't has action listener, so when the button is get clicked nothing is happen t.stop(); never get call. we need to register endbut to the same action listener.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with the additional information. The explanation will get lost among the comments.